# How to build jansson using premake?

Tags: c, json, cmake, premake

I am trying to build [jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.2/apiref.html) C library using premake.

The designers of the library require us to:

- ./configure
- make
- make install

the above steps generates jansson_config.h that is needed for the build.

What I want to do is:

- ./configure
- premake4 gmake
- make

What happens when I do that is that the build fails saying that jansson_config.h is missing.

How would I be able to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why do you want to run Premake here? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I am building Jansson library as part of a bigger project. All libraries will be eventually statically compiled so that 1 single binary is generated. Since I am using premake for my project, I wanted all the build steps included inside the premake.
Yes I can instruct premake to run prebuildcommands to run cmake first and I would link directly with the generated binary. But it would be perfect if I can build with premake directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building with other build systems than those directly supported by Jansson is documented here: https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/gettingstarted.html#other-systems

Basically, you just take `src/jansson_config.h.in`, copy it to `src/jansson_config.h` and edit it, replacing all `@var@` placeholders to match your target system.